# Getting error while trying to call a variable value in Python

Tags: python

I'm using Python for a class homework. I store the value of the variable using the following

```
foods = (x[0] for x in data)
```

I then create a binary variable for later use in a constraint

```
selectvars = LpVariable.dicts("Select",foods, lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat="Binary")
```

When I wrote the constraint below and tried to run, Python flagged the following error:

```
prob2 += (selectvars['Frozen Broccoli'] + selectvars['Celery, Raw']) <= 1
```

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
31
32 # Constraint on broccoli and celery
---> 33 prob2 += (selectvars['Frozen Broccoli'] + selectvars['Celery, Raw']) <= 1

KeyError: 'Frozen Broccoli'

Can someone please help explain why I received the error? I checked the variables in "foods" and Frozen Broccoli was definite one of the values.

Comment: What "selectvars" returns after assigment? `print(selectvars)`

Comment: You checked the value in `foods`, but you try to access `selectvars`.

Comment: @SalamanderKrajza It returns {}

Comment: @Matthias Yes, in the variable dictionary defined above, I already `selectvars` to take value from `foods`

Comment: Looks like your "selectvars" is empty dict and thats why you can't access 'Frozen Broccoli'. How is your "foods" looks?`print(foods)` And what kind of output you're expecting at the end?

Comment: @SalamanderKrajza
`print(foods)` returns `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001E6D24D33C0>`

Alternatively if I do 
`for i in foods:
   print (i)`

It returns the actual food values:

Frozen Broccoli
Carrots,Raw
Celery, Raw
Frozen Corn
Lettuce,Iceberg,Raw
Peppers, Sweet, Raw
Potatoes, Baked
Tofu
Roasted Chicken

Comment: @SalamanderKrajza I am trying to build a constraint for an optimization problem, basically saying that we're allowed to have at most one broccoli or celery. `selectvars` is a binary variable.

Comment: Tbh. i never used LpVariable.dicts before, but as i've checked if i have single-character-long in my foods elements then selectvars is creating some dict with values `{'F': Select_F, 'C': Select_C, 'R': Select_R, 'L': Select_L, 'I': Select_I, 'S': Select_S, 'B': Select_B}` but when in my food i have entire names it is empty `{}`; Are you sure it is possible to have longer keys in binary variable?

Comment: Your food as you mentioned returns entire names instead single character. Maybe you need `x[0][0]` instead `x[0]` to make it single-character-long?

Comment: @SalamanderKrajza Thanks so much for your help. I copied the code over to a new notebook and it runs now. Not sure what happened in the previous notebook but it runs well in the new notebook now.